# Default permissions with setfacl

Tags: linux, permissions

Just started using `setfacl` to assign permissions for a specific group to /var/www/html (CentOS 5).  Files in this directory are 640, root:apache.  However, I've noticed that after doing something like:

```
setfacl -R -m g:developers:rwx /var/www/html
setfacl -R -m d:g:developers:rwx /var/www/html
```

... `ls -al` shows that a newly created file's owner and group are both set to my username.

Is there a way (using `setfacl`) to enforce newly created files to get the permissions of the ACLs AND then set the owner:group to root:apache?  Or, alternatively, is this best done through a periodic cron job that does a `chown -R root.apache /var/www/html` down the entire DocumentRoot?  Or... am I missing something else completely?

Comment: Maybe it's sufficient to ensure that all files that get created are owned and writable by group `developers`? You could do that by setting the setgid bit on `/var/www/html` and using umask 002.

Comment: The `setfacl -R -m d:g:developers:rwx /var/www/html` ensures that newly created files can be modified and deleted by anyone in `developers`.  setgid is great for allowing apache to still see the files - doing a `chmod g+s` on the directory forces newly created files to be owned by username:apache instead of username:username.  The actual owner isn't much of a problem because the only users that should be in that directory are a) in `developers` or b) root.  Keeping `/var/www/html` as 750, root:apache (with the setgid bit) ensures users outside of `developers` can't get into the directory.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure new files are owned by the developers group, set g+s and set the default permissions to read, write and execute.

```
chown -R :developers /var/www/html
chmod -R g+s /var/www/html
setfacl -d -m g::rwx /var/www/html
```

Comment: @steen-chutt In `setfacl/getfacl`, does `g::rwx` refer to the Linux standard file permission group owner rights ? Does `u::rwx` refer to Linux standard file permission owner rights ?

Comment: @SebMa Yes. You can also put a group ID in between the colons to set the permissions for a specific group other than the one owning the file. I recommend taking a look at the man page for `setfacl`, specifically the section "ACL ENTRIES", which goes into more detail on the format :)